# Simulating background task on AppHarbor

Tags: appharbor, memorycache

I'm using System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache to simulate a repeated task on a running .NET MVC application deployed on AppHarbor.

Entries in the cache are added using a CacheItemPolicy which contains an AbsoluteExpiration offset and a RemovedCallback that calls a method and retriggers the adding of the item in the cache (as described [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/))

MemoryCache is populated first time in Application_Start. It works fine locally, but doesn't seem to work once deployed on AppHarbor (tried also with HttpRuntime.Cache, same result).

My application is running under a CANOE (free) account on AppHarbor that only has one worker. Does this mean that I won't be able to simulate the background task until I upgrade to some paid plan?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your application has to have visitors every once in a while for this to work. Other than StillAlive, Pingdom is also a good bet for generating requests to your app. You should also take a look at [MomentApp](http://momentapp.com/). We expect to have background tasks ready shortly.

Comment: how can you propose monitoring as a mean to implement a functionality?  having a feature relying on the status of monitoring seems really amateurish to me. Can you answer the question why the cache callback is not called properly? thank you.

Comment: @ChakerNakhli I don't know your cache callback is not called, it's your app. Pingdom and StillAlive create requests to your application to that the cache callback gets a chance to be fired. thank you.

Comment: First, I really love appharbor. It is defeniely a great idea. However, monitoring is meant to *monitor* application's state and measure its performance. You should *never* have your application logic rely on how monitoring is done or implemented. You should minimize the probe effect; not rely on it. I you rely on monitoring, it means that if ops decide to change it, they'll simply break the app! Not acceptable in real  life. Sorry but encouraging people to use monitoring to implement workers makes appharbor appear as a toy for amateurs and not a solid platform thought for real life apps.

Comment: The reason you'll end up relying on monitoring is because you're building a solution for running backgound workers that relies on cache expiry. I'm not telling you to rely on monitoring, I'm just trying to help you get your code to work. If you don't want to use Stillalive or Pingdom, MomentApp should work. You might want to also check out Phil Haacks webbackgrounder project: https://github.com/NuGet/WebBackgrounder

Comment: Sorry, I thought the comments from @ChakerNakhli were from the original asker, my mistake.

Comment: I knew about Phil Haacks' WebBackgrounder but I didn't know about the MomentApp service. Thank you for your answer and long live to AppHarbor! :-)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I retested the application using the cache trick, seems to work now. Might have been a temporary problem. Integrating with StillAlive also works, though the free plan allows pinging the server only once each 4 hours.

Comment: MomentApp is MIA. Perhaps http://binarycanary.com/en/uptime-monitoring-pricing.cfm instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think upgrading will help, they are working on adding background jobs to AppHarbor but to my knowledge they available yet.

What about using a service like https://stillalive.com/ to periodically hit a page on your site that then spins up a new thread and starts running your background task? Its available as a free add-on.

I was thinking of doing something like this while waiting for the background task functionality to be available.

Comment: I was thinking of polling a page from outside, but my task takes some time to finish. AppHarbor timeouts requests after 10 seconds or so and I don't know if the action is still executed or not.